# Remove yourself as a guest from another Teams organisation

Tags: teams

I have an end user that would like to remove from his Teams the presence of an organisation that he was working with. Whilst I can find guides to accomplish this and get to an end point where you can click on "leave organisation", these all seem to work on the premise that access to the guest org is still in place such that you can get in so that you can leave. Anyone know how to remove the presence when the access had been revoked by the 3rd party?

[image: Screenshot showing the account I want to remove]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guest user can't leave an organization if their account is disabled in either the home tenant or the resource tenant. If their account is disabled, the guest user will need to contact the tenant admin, who can either delete the guest account or enable the guest account so the user can leave the organization.